# Ошибка открытия файла с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Написал код для записи и чтения информации из файла
При открытии файла выдает ошибку чтения файла

```
ifstream mfile("managersRegister.txt", ios_base::in);
mfile.open("managersRegister.txt");
if(!mfile)
{
    cout << "\nОшибка открытия файла.";
    exit(1);
}
do
{
    mfile >> larr[i].login;
    mfile >> larr[i].password;
} while (!mfile.eof());
```

Comment: Зачем же открывать уже открытый файл? первые две строчки замените на `ifstream mfile("managersRegister.txt");` и убедитесь, что файл действительно есть и находится **в текущем каталоге**.

Comment: А зачем Вы один и тот же файл открываете дважды? Строка с open не нужна